# How can I make task start date and finish date dependent upon the start & finish dates of one predecessor?

Tags: dependencies

Example: new housing scheme, constructing 10 houses on separate plots. Brickwork can begin 5 days after the 20-day tasks of scaffolding being erected. However, brickwork can't finish until 5 days after scaffolding has finished being erected.

How do I link the start & finish of the brickwork to the start and finish dates of the scaffolding being put up? MSProject says I can't give one task 2 links to the same predecessor task.....

All help gratefully received..

Comment: If Brickwork can only start 5 days after Scaffolding completes, how is it possible for Brickwork to finish anything less than 5 days after Scaffolding completes?

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't clear. Brickwork can only start 5 days after scaffolding starts (not complete). Brickwork can only finish 5 days after scaffolding finishes.. I hope that's clearer

Answer (score 1):

I would have 3 tasks.

1 Scafolding
2 Scafolding Complete (Milestone) linked to TID:1 
3 Brickwork 1SS+20d, 2FF+5 days

That will give you what you want. As you say in project you can only have 1 link to the same predecessor task.

Comment: Thanks Richard. That'd work, although it's a little clumsy. I'm surprised MSP can't cope with this set of dependencies. It must crop up a lot.....I feel a suggestion to MS coming on........Thx again

Comment: Another spin - two milestone tasks (begin scaffolding and end scaffolding) which are SS and FF linked (respectively) to the scaffolding task, which is 20 days long.  Then Brickwork linked appropriately.